# Oracle - tools to track changes made to a row in descriptive manner

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, audit

Our database has ROW LEVEL trigger which keeps track of changes in a separate schema.

For example : SCHEMA_A.table_1 will have a corresponding AUDIT_SCHEMA.table_1.

The AUDIT_SCHEMA.table_1 will have all the columns in SCHEMA_A and few additional columns ( date/time of change, who made changes etc.)

One can always do the following to track changes made to a row

SELECT col_1, col_2,...col_N FROM Schema_A.table_1 where primary_key_column = N
union
SELECT col_1, col_2,...col_N FROM audit_schema.table_1 where primary_key_column = N
order by .....

But once we have more than say 10-15 columns, browsing over output become onerous.

Also - most of time only 1 or 2 columns have changed, but we end up printing all other columns also.

So - we want to track all the changes made to a row in descriptive fashion as follows :

```
  Table_1. Primary Key value = N

  Aug 01 : col_1 changed from A to M by user_X
  Aug 02 : col_9 changed from 10 to 99 by user_M
  Aug 03 : col_5 changed from "Jan 20" to NULL by user_X
  Aug 06 : col_1 changed from M to Q by user_Y
```

Are there any utility/tools available which I can use to accomplish above ?

Comment: If you have an Enterprise Edition you can create a flashback archive, then you can query old versions of the rows and compare them.

Comment: Will using FlashBack Archive give me list of changes in descriptive fashion as I mentioned above ?

Comment: You can build that description from the result of such a query. Although I don't think it would include the user doing the UPDATE - for that you would need to enable complete auditing

Comment: Voting to reopen. I don't think there's going to be any pre-built tool to accomplish this, but I'm sure it could be done with a table function that accepts a table name and primary key value and uses dynamic SQL to generate a change description.